# How can I query the form that caused ajax call from callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have several forms on my page with the same structure and classes.

I want to send form data to the server using POST method, and show error message if something went wrong.

So, HTML code for the forms:

```
<form class="js-form">
  <input name="data" type="text" required>
  <button type="submit" value="Go">Go Form 1</button>
</form>
<div class="js-alert" style="display:none;">Error Message</div>

<br><br><br>

<form class="js-form">
  <input name="data" type="text" required>
  <button type="submit" value="Go">Go Form 2</button>
</form>
<div class="js-alert" style="display:none;">Error Message</div>
```

and the js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).find("input[name='data']").val(),
        url = "/api/method";
    var posting = $.post(url, {data: data});

    posting.done(function(res) {
        $("input[name='data']").val(''); // empty all inputs in all forms
        console.log(res);
    });

    posting.fail(function(res) {
        // here I want to show the alert 
        // that is next to a form user had interacted with
    });
});
```

I've tried `$.proxy` and `this` binding, but the context in `posting.fail()` is always the same (request context). How could I get to the form context and query closest alert sibling?

Comment: You should be able to preserve `this` in another variable outside of the `fail` function and then use it inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options:

Utilize the `event` argument to the `submit` callback (`event.target` points to the form):

```
posting.fail(function(res) {
   console.log('do something with form', event.target)
});
```

Capture the context `this` into a variable outside of your `posting.fail` callback:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // capture context!
    var form = this;
    var data = $(this).find("input[name='data']").val(),
        url = "/api/method";

    var posting = $.post(url, {data: data});

    posting.done(function(res) {
        $("input[name='data']").val(''); // empty all inputs in all forms
        console.log(res);
    });

    posting.fail(function(res) {
        console.log('do something with form', form)
    });
});
```

If you can support ES6, this is much simpler - just use an arrow function:

```
posting.fail((res) => {
   console.log('do something with form', this)
});
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed options desctiption. I chose capturing context, since it seems most readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(this)` as this will reference the form that was submitted.

However, since the scope of `this` in your callback will be different you will need to define it outside the callback function.

```
var that = $(this);
```

so your code will look like this:

```
var that = $(this);

//rest of code
posting.fail(function(res) {
    $(that).html(res);
});
```

See complete code snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".js-form").submit(function(event) {
        var that = $(this); //reference to form submitted on
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).find("input[name='data']").val(),
          url = "/api/method";
        var posting = $.post(url, {
          data: data
        });

        posting.done(function(res) {
          $("input[name='data']").val(''); // empty all inputs in all forms
          console.log(res);
        });

        posting.fail(function(res) {
          //can now reference the form submitted here
          that.html(res);
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `context` option of `$.ajax()` settings to an object, where `this` should be the same object set at the value for `context` property within jQuery `.then()`, `.done()`, `.fail()` and other deferred methods. Not sure how code used `$.proxy`, though that is also an option that can be used.

```
   $.ajax({/* settings, */ context:{} /* set `this` here */})
   .then(function() {
     // `this` : `this` set at `context`
   })
   .fail(function() {
     // `this` : `this` set at `context`
   })
```